# The same code does not work in headless mode [playwright]

Tags: headless, playwright

```
"": "^1.23.0",
```

In headless=false, it works.
In headless=true, I cannot pass this line:

```
await this.page.dispatchEvent('button[role="tab"]:has-text("Hello")', 'click')
```

and the error is:

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

page.dispatchEvent: Target crashed
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "button[role="tab"]:has-text("Hello")"
============================================================
    at Scrapper4_save.main (file:///Users/yo/0HOME/0GARAGE/demo/src/e2e/0-ts-out/e2e/Scrapper4_save.js:20:25)
    at async file:///Users/yo/0HOME/0GARAGE/demo/src/e2e/0-ts-out/e2e/index.js:34:13 {
  name: 'Error'
}
```

Is it posible to have the exact same working code in headless or headed mode ?
Do you know how to fix this issue ?
Tks

Comment: I could not reproduce, found it to work both headed and headless. Is there something about the HTML that's unusual?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. This generally happens when the site is trying to block you and is able to detect you as a bot when headless, but not when headful. I believe usually Cloudflare. You can print the page content to see what they're sending you--it could be a captcha or similar. But yeah... without the page it's impossible to assist.

Comment: See [Headless dont work using playwright beautifulsoup 4 and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72887356/headless-dont-work-using-playwright-beautifulsoup-4-and-python/72999870#72999870)